# VS Code doesn't highlight C# errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, runtime-error

I started a C# project with this command

```
dotnet new console -o Zeyad
```

And I wrote this code inside the `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = "Zeyad";
    int age = "16";
    Console.WriteLine(age);
}
```

The problem is that VS Code didn't underline the variable age as the value mismatched the type (string instead of integer).

And it didn't highlight `name` as it's not used (and didn't even turn its color to grey!)

I was a Golang developer before and VS Code was always underlining errors like those.

And yes I installed the C# extension.

Please note that I'm on a Mac

[image]

Comment: You should install some additional extensions, like Roslynator, FxCop, StyleCop.

Comment: I couldn't find the last two in vs code extension market, how can I find them? Tho the first one was enough to finally highlight those errors, thank you so much!